# Invalid probability model for large support vector machines using ksvm in R

Tags: r, kernlab

I train support vector machines using the `ksvm` function from the kernlab package in R, on large numbers of observations (300k) with not very many features (1-8). I want to use the resulting probability model, but for large data sets, the resulting probability model has an unexpected format.

This is what should happen:

```
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(label=c(rep("x",n),rep("y",n)),value=c(runif(n),runif(n)+2))
m <- ksvm(label~value,df,prob.model=TRUE)

> prob.model(m)
[[1]]
[[1]]$A
[1] -6.836228

[[1]]$B
[1] 0.003163229
```

However, for large values of `n` (e.g. 100k; beware of high memory usage and long execution times), the value of `prob.model(m)[[1]]` is a numeric vector of length `2n`, seemingly the likelihood for each observation in `df`. What could cause this?

Session info:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     stats     methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] kernlab_0.9-16   e1071_1.6-1      class_7.3-5      data.table_1.8.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.2
```

**Edit:** this is a classification task I'm talking about, `df` has the following form:

```
label value
"x"    0.21
...
"x"   -1.20
"y"    2.42
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of the problem is indicated by the following error message:

```
line search fails
```

A more specific question, including the original data frame I used, is here: [Line search fails in training ksvm prob.model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895897).