# Line search fails in training ksvm prob.model

Tags: r, svm, kernlab

Following up from [Invalid probability model for large support vector machines using ksvm in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830718):

I am training an SVM using ksvm from the kernlab package in R. I want to use the probability model, but during the sigmoid fitting I get the following error message:

```
line search fails -1.833726 0.5772808 5.844462e-05 5.839508e-05 -1.795008e-08 
-1.794263e-08 -2.096847e-12
```

When this happens, the resulting value of `prob.model(m)` is a vector of all probabilities, rather than the expected parameters of a sigmoid function fitted over these probabilities. What causes this error and how can I prevent it? Searching for the error message yielded no results.

Reproducible example:

```
load(url('http://roelandvanbeek.nl/files/df.rdata'))
ksvm(label~value,df[1:1000],C=10,prob.model=TRUE)->m 
prob.model(m) # works as it should, prints a list containing one named list

# the below, non-working problem, unfortunately takes an hour due to the large
# sample size
ksvm(label~value,df,C=10,prob.model=TRUE)->m # line search fails  
prob.model(m) # just a vector of values
```

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: No. I did found that it also occurs with smaller data sets, but have not yet been able to find a consistent explanation. Often, reducing or increasing the number of observations fixes the problem, which adds to the irregularity of its nature...

Comment: @roelandvanbeek, i see the problem when i try to plot the learning curve for my dataset, but when i run only for certain splits 70/30 for example, it does not show the issue? is this what you mean by reducing or increasing observations?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, [this is the line that throws that error](https://github.com/cran/kernlab/blob/master/R/ksvm.R#L3092).

It's on the method `.probPlatt` using the Newton method to optimize the function, in this case Platt's scaling. If you check [line 3007](https://github.com/cran/kernlab/blob/master/R/ksvm.R#L3007) though you'll see some parameters pertaining to the method.

One of such parameters is `minstep` basically the minimal numeric step the method should keep trying to optimize the function. You see, this is exactly the condition of the error in line 3090: `if (stepsize < minstep)`. So, basically, the function is not converging, even when reaching the minimum step size.

You can try changing `minstep` to lower values to circumvent it. Alexandros even commented these parameters should probably be in the interface.

Comment: are you saying that we should change the code and recompile it ?

Comment: @EB Yes about changing the code, recompilation isn't strictly required though.

Comment: @catastrophic-failure I do not understand the behavior of the optimizer. if max iteration is reached, no problem. but if step is lower than min_step it calls `.SigmoidPredict` which does not return A and B. I do not think that the solution is to decrease min_step, but not to call `.SigmoidPredict`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem occurs randomly. Thus, I circumvented the problem by fitting the ksvm model as many times until it worked.

```
stop.crit = 1
while (stop.crit <= 10) {
    stop.crit = stop.crit + 1
    MOD = ksvm(...)
    tryCatch(PRED = predict(...), error = function(e) e)
    if (exists("PRED") == TRUE) stop.crit = 11
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the behavior of the optimizer. if max iteration is reached, no problem. but if step is lower than min_step it calls `.SigmoidPredict` which does not return `A` and `B`. I do not think that the solution is to decrease `min_step`, but not to call `.SigmoidPredict`, so I commented it out. btw, I do not understand why they do not use glm to estimate A and B.

here's a repository based on the latest source from cran with the call to SigmoidPredict commented out.

`devtools::install_github('elad663/kernlab')`