# kernlab class prediction calculations failed => with SVMLinear NOT SVMRadial

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

I got a problem training SVMLinear with caret. The data works just fine with SVMRadial though.

The data is accessible via (29/05/2016): 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ia2vc25uhxdgqn1/projetTest01.txt?dl=0

(8000 lines of 1021 variables, ~10% target)

Here's the code:

```
projetTest01<-read.table("projetTest01.txt", sep="\t")
Test01<-list(data=projetTest01[,-c(2,3)],label=projetTest01[,3])
Test01N<-Test01

Test01N$label<-as.factor(Test01$label)
levels(Test01N$label)[levels(Test01N$label)=="0"] <- "No"
levels(Test01N$label)[levels(Test01N$label)=="1"] <- "Yes"

temp<-as.matrix(Test01$data)
storage.mode(temp) <- "numeric"     #I need 'num' type
Test01N$data<-as.data.frame(temp)

svmTuneGrid_L <- data.frame(.C = 2^(-2:7))
trControl_SVML<-trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 3, classProbs =  TRUE)
svmFit_Lin <- train(Test01N$label ~ ., data = Test01N$data,method = "svmLinear",preProc = c("center", "scale"), tuneGrid = svmTuneGrid_L,trControl = trControl_SVML)
```

And I got these messages:

line search fails [..]

Warning in method$predict(modelFit = modelFit, newdata = newdata, submodels = param) :
  kernlab class prediction calculations failed; returning NAs

Warning in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded

I looked up the site/the web for some answers, but

- the levels aren't numeric (=yes/no)
- the ClassProb is set to TRUE
- the labels can't be predicted perfectly from another variable (I know this from other algorithms)
- there isn't a empty class
- preproc(scale) or not doesn't make a difference
- And the data works just fine with SVMRadial!!
- I use caret 6.0-68

I really am at a loss. An idea someone?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895897/line-search-fails-in-training-ksvm-prob-model